# Shifting all the values in an array one index higher with the displaced last element placed as the first element

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with the below code in JS please help:

Currently trying to get

[20,30,40,50]

to be

[50,20,30,40]

any tips?

Here is the code I have so far below!

```
// A program to shift all the values in an array one index higher, with the displaced last element being placed as the first element

var test = [20,30,40,50];

for (i=0; i<test.length;i++)
{
    alert(test[i] + " is currently index: " + [i]); 
    }

test[0] = test[test.length-1];

for (i=0; i<test.length;i++)
{
    alert(test[i] + " is now index: " + [i+1]); 
    }
```

Comment: Does [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) and [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) not work?

Comment: @JaredFarrish `push()` adds to the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do this:

```
a.unshift(a.pop());
```

Comment: I knew `.pop()` would be in there somewhere.

Comment: @alex That array had it comin'.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be different...

```
a.slice(-1).concat(a.slice(0, -1));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c665v/).

Comment: The sick part is that was actually what I thought of *first* :/ (Almost that, anyway.) +1 for taking that mold and smashing it with our brains.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using splice(), not pretty enough though

```
arr.splice(0, 0, arr.splice(arr.length-1, 1));
```

Comment: Nah; +1 -- seeing alternatives is educational.